# Is the world balanced around the number of players?

Tags: dont-starve-together

When I play Don't Starve Together, I always feel like the generated world was made for a single player game.

I usually play with two friends but we usually end up starving pretty soon (20ish days) since we all try to supply on the same sources. Don't get me wrong, we all work together so triple work (farms, beehives, spiders) should equal triple food. It doesn't seem to add up properly since we end up lacking seeds or other basic supplies soon.
I can't imagine if we were to be six players.
 Simply because resources around us get collected more frequently and we start missing  resources very soon.

We are pretty experienced players with all our solo worlds advanced so we know how to survive properly.

The only way I see around this would be to all go separate ways completely far enough to get our little personal world but then again, what is the point of playing in the same world if you play like this.

So, are the world generated with the number of players in mind or does it simply generate a similar world without thinking of how many players will play in it?

Comment: I doubt it, Don't Starve Together is early access for a reason. I'd wait for it to become more mature since the original game was heavily based on being single player.

Comment: @Thebluefish That's what I thought. It's unfortunate since it's at the very core of the multiplayer gameplay but I guess I'll just have to wait and see. I just hope someone can come up with a definitive answer they got somewhere.

Comment: I disagree with the off-topic flag for being unreleased. Technically, this game is available publicly through legitimate means. "Early Access" is just another (admittedly good) excuse for "the game isn't finished, but we'll release it anyways".

Answer (score 8):

Currently it's the same generation as single player. This is bound to change but as of now, I just set things slightly higher that DON'T reproduce.

There's a huge thread on multiplayer servers here - http://forums.kleientertainment.com/topic/45915-what-makes-a-good-dst-world/

That should help :)